# Using localStorage to store a display preference

Tags: javascript

Currently, I am hiding a sidebar with javascript (When I click a button the menu hides, click it again, it appears back)

I did some research on localStorage and nothing prevailed. I am wondering if I am able to set a simple user preference using this method. All the JS does is change the elements display property. Sorry the code is in the same section (The big break indicates HTML after)

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   if(e.style.display == 'block')
       e.style.display = 'none';
   else
       e.style.display = 'block';
}





<div class="col-sm-2">
         <i id="collapse" class="fa fa-bars fa-lg" onclick="toggle_visibility('communitiesWrapper');" style="position:absolute;"></i>
          <div id="communitiesWrapper">
               <div id="communitiesHeader">
                 <center><h4 style="font-weight: 700;">Communities &amp; Teams</h4></center>
               </div>
               <div id="communitiesMenu">
                 <ul class="listofcommunities">
                   <li><i class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i>PCMasterRace</li>
                   <li><i class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i>Steam</li>
                   <li><i class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i>Corsair</li>
                   <li><i class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i>Web development</li>
                   <li><i class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i>Font Awesome</li>
                 </ul>
                 <hr>
                 <ul class="listofteams">
                   <li><i class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i>Project A</li>
                   <li><i class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i>Project B</li>
                   <li><i class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i></i>Project C</li>
                   <li><i class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i></i>Project A</li>
                   <li><i class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i></i>Project B</li>
                   <li><i class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i></i>Project C</li>
                   <li><i class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i></i>Project A</li>
                   <li><i class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i></i>Project B</li>
                   <li><i class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i></i>Project C</li>
                   <li><i class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i></i>Project A</li>
                 </ul>
               </div>
          </div>
       </div>
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use ***localStorage.setItem*** and ***localStorage.getItem*** methods. You have to bind a function to the side bar (onClick) to store user's preference. If the used hides the side bar, the function should do:

```
localStorage.setItem("showSideBar", "no");
```

and set it to ***yes*** if the opposite.

And then whenever you load the page, check for this value to decide whether to show the side bar or not:

```
var show = localStorage.getItem("showSideBar");

if show == "yes":
     #show the side bar
else:
     #hide the side bar
```

Comment: Hm, what would I need to add the existing OnClick ?

Comment: In your if statement add "localStorage.setItem("showSideBar", "no");" and in the else statement add localStorage.setItem("showSideBar", "yes");